# Regex Pattern for Mobile Number Verification Problem

Tags: java, regex, user-interface

I don't know what's wrong with my code, all I want is to accept a mobile number with this kind of format: 09xxxxxxxxx (Always starts in "09" and with a total of 11 digits). All efforts would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[Here is the picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnHc1.png)

Here are the codes:

```
String a2= jTextField6.getText();
String a3 = jTextField7.getText();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(09) \\d {9}$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(jTextField5.getText());

if (!m.matches()){         
     int b = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Mobile Number", "Error", b);    
     return;
}
if (null==a2||a2.trim().isEmpty()){
     int b = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Fields should not left blank", "Error", b);
     return;
} 
if(a3==null||a3.trim().isEmpty()){
     int b = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Fields should not left blank", "Error", b);  
}

else { 
    int c = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
    int d = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Confirm Purchase?","Costume 1", c);
    if (d==0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"Your costume will be delivered 3-5 working days." +"\n"+"\n"+"                   Thank You!");
    }
```

Comment: Why are there spaces in your pattern?

Comment: why? Is that a reason why I encounter error?

Comment: Remove spaces, this works for me : "^(09)\\d{9}$"

Comment: still says "Invalid Number" to me huhu

Comment: Thanks guys, it works. I made a mistake sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the blank spaces in your regex:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(09)\\d{9}$");
```

otherwise they are gonna be considered as characters that must be present.

Answer (score 1):

Use *comments mode* to ignore whitespace in a regex pattern. This can be done either by passing the `Pattern.COMMENTS` flag when compiling the regex pattern, or via the embedded flag expression `(?x)`.

**Example 1:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(09) \\d {9}$", Pattern.COMMENTS);
```

**Example 2:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?x)^(09) \\d {9}$");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    final String regex = "^09\\d{9}$";
    final String string = "09518390956"; //matcb
    //final String string = "11518390956"; // fails
    //final String string = "09518390956 "; // fails

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    }
```

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: I was answering the question... a regex meeting the following criteria: starting with "09" and with a total of 11 digits

Comment: Are you sure? Your regex matches 9 digits! And why using `Pattern.MULTILINE`?

Comment: @Toto you are right, I misread the question. I updated my solution based on your comments